# Flyway- schema migration

Tags: database, liquibase, flyway

I have few tables in production environment with data in it.  I want to add new tables retaining the existing tables with data in it.

I tried using flyway but for that initial schema (schema with which existing production tables and data were created) also need to be set and drop the existing tables.  However, in my use case I do not want my existing tables to be deleted.

Comment: read [this](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html)

Comment: If you have an existing schema, you need to use flyway baseline to tell it what version it's at, so it only runs scripts higher than that version.